# Map the max function for list of the lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I stack with the following problem, I need to finding maximum between equal positions between lists. Map function works pretty well, but how to make it work for the list of the lists? using map(max,d) gave the max of the every list. The problem is that the number of the lists in the list is variable. Any suggestions are welcome!
Input for the problem is `d` not an `a,b,c`, d - is a list of the lists, and the comparison is pairwise per position in the list.

```
a = [0,1,2,6]
b = [5,1,0,7]
c = [3,8,0,8]
map(max,a,b,c)
# [5,8,2,8]
d = [a,b,c]
map(max,d)
[6,7,8]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
a = [0,1,2,6]
b = [5,1,0,7]
c = [3,8,0,8]

print [max(itm) for itm in zip(a, b, c)]
```

or even shorter:

```
print map(max, zip(a, b, c))
```

Comment: The unpacking in `max(*itm)` isn't required here... you can keep it as a tuple `max(itm)`

Comment: @JonClements thanks, edited. And it turned out, max can by directly applied via map to the zipped list.

Comment: Of course it can, as you've in effect just re-written the list-comp using `map` - even `map(max, a, b, c)` avoiding the `zip` is valid :) Athough it's important to note the behaviour of `map` differs from `zip` in the length of sequences it will take... `map()` will take the longest and default padding to `None`s causing potential errors, while `zip` will short-circuit on the shortest... As long as they're identical lengths - either is fine...

Comment: @JonClements looking to the final line of code, I would call it "Python waltz", all follows pattern of three, three functions called, three variables used, just the parenthesis are getting out of it (but with waltz, dancers are also dancing in couples) :-)

Comment: @John how do you not get `[5, 8, 2, 8]`?

Comment: @JohnAmraph and do you get something different?

Comment: @John then you unpack `d`, such as `map(max, *d)` which effectively makes the call `map(max, a, b, c)` or similar for the arguments using the `zip` approach

Comment: FANTASTIC! That works! post it as an answer, I will accept it

Comment: @John sorry - it wasn't overly clear in the your OP it was just unpacking you were looking for :)

Comment: @John I'm sure Jan can amend the post to reflect the real question after your update you were asking :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

`max(map(max,d))`

Comment: nope, the comparison is pairwise for all lists in the d'